# Are there any programming languages with implicit multiplication?

Tags: syntax, programming-languages

Is there a programming language in which any of the following:

- a numeric literal next to a variable `3x`, `-0.5y`
- a numeric literal or numeric variable next to a parenthesized expression `a(b+c+d)` `2(x-y)`
- two adjacent parenthesized expressions `(1+x)(1-x)` `(4a-5b)(1+4c)`

is interpreted to mean a multiplication?

I can see the syntactical problems that this would cause, but I'm curious if any language has gone ahead and done it anyway.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about choice of programming languages

Answer (score 5):

[TI-BASIC does it](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/multiply) in certain circumstances. I believe that certain CAS oriented langauges do as well.

Answer (score 3):

IIRC, [Fortress](http://projectfortress.java.net/) has a "juxtaposition operator" that for numeric types is defined as multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

Some high level languages, such [Mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SolvingEquations.html), are capable of dealing with symbols rather than plain vars. You can try to query [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3x%2b4y) in a same fashion too, omitting the multiplication operator.