# How do I make an Int8 literal in Julia?

Tags: julia, literals

I can make "literals" of type `Int64` and even `Uint8` in Julia:

```
julia> typeof(8)
Int64

julia> typeof(0x08)
Uint8
```

But I haven't been able to find out how to make a literal of type `Int8`. I have tried a few different things:

```
julia> 8::Int8
ERROR: type: typeassert: expected Int8, got Int64

julia> 0x08::Int8
ERROR: type: typeassert: expected Int8, got Uint8

julia> convert(Int8, 8)
8

julia> typeof(ans)
Int8
```

So the application of the `convert` function worked, but that's a somewhat wordy expression. I was wondering if there was something a little more concise, perhaps like Rust's 8i8.

I am using Julia 0.3.3, but answers for Julia 0.4.x would be fine too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

More convenient than  `convert(Int8, 8)` is `Int8(8)` respective `int8(8)` on earlier versions. The reason that few number literal notations like `8i8` exist is that it conflicts with multiplication by juxtaposition.

```
julia> i8=8
8

julia> 3i8
24
```

Comment: Thanks, I was stuck using Julia 0.3.x, where `Int8(8)` gave me `ERROR: type cannot be constructed`. I did not notice the `int8` convert function. So many things have been massively improved with major backwards incompatibilities. I can't want for 0.4 to come out. Hope it does soon.

Comment: Btw, you can make transition to 0.4 easier with https://github.com/JuliaLang/Compat.jl .

Comment: [Multiplication by juxtaposition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18136361/are-there-any-programming-languages-with-implicit-multiplication) seems to be a relatively uncommon language feature. Does Julia's syntax allow it?